# Database user logging solution that works for all versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logging, audit-logging

I need to log all users connecting to our productions SQL Servers (user, database)

Need to implement this for a production environment with every version of SQL Server (SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014)

Comment: Most aren't a problem - but SQL Server **2000** is soooooo hopelessly outdated, unsupported, insecure - that'll either "drag down" any solution you find (and make it next to useless on the newer version), or that'll be the stumbling block for solutions not to work. It's about **highest time** to upgrade!

Comment: ok...how about excluding SQL Server 2000? Is there a solution that works for all other versions?

Comment: Check out [login triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) introduced in SQL Server 2005